# Serilog logging part of message in Azure Application Insight

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

After searching lot on google and trying to find what could be the problem, logged issue in github repo where from I had read about serilog implmentation in .Net Core function app - https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/issues/179

Serilog is not logging complete message in Azure application insights, no idea what could be the reason. However on console it is logging complete message. Below is code snippet in Startup.cs

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var logger = ConfigureLogging();
            builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(logger));
        }
        

   private Logger ConfigureLogging()
        {
            var telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            telemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey =
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");

            int defaultLoggingSwitch = 3;//Warning
            int tloggingSwitch = 3;//Warning
            int tSloggingSwitch = 3;//Warning
            Int32.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DefaultLogging"), out defaultLoggingSwitch);
            Int32.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMPLoggingSwitch"), out tloggingSwitch);
            Int32.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TESLoggingSwitch"), out tSloggingSwitch);

            LoggingLevelSwitch SeriLogLevelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch((LogEventLevel)defaultLoggingSwitch);
            LoggingLevelSwitch TMPLoggingSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch((LogEventLevel)tloggingSwitch);
            LoggingLevelSwitch TESLoggingSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch((LogEventLevel)tSloggingSwitch);


            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(SeriLogLevelSwitch)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("ClassName", TMPLoggingSwitch)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("IEventsService", TESLoggingSwitch)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Events)
            .CreateLogger();

            return logger;
        }
```

Consuming in Eventhub based function app as shown below -

Injecting logger in Function App class -

```
public EventHubProcessing(ITypeService teService, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, ILogger<ISampleClass> logger)
    {
        log = logger;
    }
```

Run method below -

```
 public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("%EVENTHUB-RECIEVE%", Connection = "EVENTHUB-RECIEVE-CONN",ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroup%")] EventData[] events, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext executionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);
                    log.LogInformation($"Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {json}");
}
```

Below are nuget package versions -
[Serilog Nuget versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJiDj.png)

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: What part of the message are you missing? What size is the message?

Comment: Size is around 5KB when printed in Console. Initial part is getting printed only of 523 Bytes (checked for one message).

Answer (score 0):

There are two places in Azure Application Insight which shows log message. At one place it was not showing complete message which I think is supposed to show only initial part of log message but in another field complete message was shown. So it is not an issue at all.

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, you need to add more details since this answer doesn't current say anything. Specify which part of the portal does and doesn't show the full log message.

Comment: Apologies, I just saw your comment but currently I'm not in position to post the more details as I left that organization.